# Updating document with object field

Tags: mongodb, object, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB, learning from its documentation but can't find a way to update the document field using MongoDB shell

When I tried to insert the **"cancellation"** object with either field the query works fine.

```
db.inventory.update({},
{
  $set : { "cancellation": 
          { 
           {"date" : new Timestamp()},
           {"reason" : "null"}
          }
         }
 },
{upsert : false,multi : true})
```

It shows

> "SyntaxError: invalid property id @(shell)"

on executing this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong. Try this:

```
db.inventory.update({},{$set : { "cancellation": 
      { 
       "date" : new Timestamp(),
       "reason" : "null"
      }
     } },{upsert : false,multi : true})
```